# Dropdown menu hidden under div

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://www.clinicajardinsbenfica.pt/new.html

I'm getting so frustrated, been looking into this issue for hours. Already z-indexed almost every component on the CSS files... The dropdown menu keeps getting under the slider, any clue?

Thank you in advance, I'm starting to despair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `overflow:hidden` on the `#header` CSS rule.

Comment: that worked! thanks a lot, I'm kinda still making my first steps in web dev and learning with my mistakes. You saved me some more hours. Thanks again!