# Dropdown menu open under div

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I need help with this site: http://www.jsdkqwoj.eu/

In mobile drop down menu goes under the div. Tried z-index:9999 for the header / topnav elements and z-index:-9999 to div. Not help. Also tried this [Dropdown menu hidden under div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236923/dropdown-menu-hidden-under-div) and it is not helping.

I googled yesterday few hours and tried many things, and not helping. I also would like to get image top of the page under the header, but i am satisfied of the menu fix.

I linked the page but here is code of the top nav/header and div.

**Summary:** I want menu open over the div and image shows behind the menu dropdown. I can do dropdown menu like pushing down the div, but that is not what i want.

**CSS**

```
header {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}


.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  position: relative;
}

.topnav #myLinks {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;

}
.topnav2 a {
  text-align: center;
}

.topnav a.icon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
}

.topnav2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  color: #ff6000;
}
```

**TOPNAV**

```
        <a href="#home" class="active"><h2 class="black">OSKARI ALAJÄRVI</h2><p class="light">Portfolio</p></a>
        <div class="topnav2" id="myLinks">
            <a href="/">Home</a>
            <a href="/category/blog/">Blog</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="hamburger_bars" onclick="myFunction2(this)">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </i>
        </a>
    </div>
```

**DIV**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm pt-5 pb-5">

                <div class="etusivun_teksti" data-aos="fade-up">
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>

                    <?php the_content();?>

                <?php endwhile; endif;?>



                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-sm etusivun_kuva"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.topnav2{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
```

Add this to your css. Hope this works

Comment: I added it to .topnav and now its working. I tried ```z-index```, but i did not have ```position: relative```. Now it is working, thanks!